# Counting the number of times a Specific value appeared in a column of a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I have a list with column `status`. Some of the items in the list are approved. I need to count the Total number of approved Items.
I have to do this **using javascript**..

Comment: You could create a view with a filter that only shows items when the columns value is approved and then in the view set a count on that column.

Comment: I have to do it using javascript

Comment: You mean to say: The column `status` is of type choice field and its noticed that `approved` is added more than once. And now you want to count the number of `approved` in the column. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: yes,like that only..

Comment: @vikashkumar What have you tried till now?

Comment: i have tried a javascript code which counts the number of items in the list

Comment: @vikashkumar but you said you want to count the number of choice item `approved` in a choice field column and not the list item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/09/22/get-count-of-distinct-values-in-a-column-of-sharepoint-list-with-javascript-client-object-model/

It will count the total number of distinct values in the column of a list.

This is what i wanted to do, we just need to replace the `listname` and `columnname` in the code with the actual list name and column name.

```
function getDistinctItemsFromList(Listname) {

try {

var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(Listname);

var items = list.getItems();

context.load(items);
context.executeQueryAsync(
function () {

var itemCount = items.get_count();

var itemsarry = new Array(parseInt(itemCount) – 1);

var ListEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();

//adding values to array
for (i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
itemsarry[i] = new Array(0);
itemsarry[i][0] = items.get_item(i).get_item(ColumnName);
}

//gettig count of unique values from array
var uniqueItemsCount = 0;
var uniqueItems = {};
$.each(itemsarry, function () {
var num = this[0];
uniqueItems[num] = uniqueItems[num] + 1 || 1;
uniqueItemsCount++;
});

//uniqueItems is your array with Column value and the associated Count.

//uniqueItemsCount is how many of these distinct values exist which is 3 in our case (IT, HR and Operations)

//Now to extract the values from this array use the snippet below

var j = 0;
$.each(uniqueItems, function (itemValue, noOfItems) {
if (itemValue != ‘undefined’);
{
alert(itemValue);
alert(noOfItems);
j++;
}
});

},
function (sender, args) { alert(“error in inner request: ” + args.get_message()); }
);
}
catch (e) { alert(“Please check the WebPart Properites and the values in the specified list. Error :”+ e); }
}
```

Comment: If you have found a solution to your problem from some blog. Then I would recommend instead of posting link if you post the code it will be much helpful for other visitors if they have a similar problem. There are chances that external links may break at some point. :)

Comment: Hello, What modifications should i need to do to save the noOfItems to a column?

Comment: This solution was really helpful, so trying to save the noOfItems to associated columns, so i can do further validations. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use REST API along with CAML query.

First create a CAML query that returns all item where Status equals Approved.

```
<Query>
<Where>
<Eq>
  <FieldRef Name="Status" />
  <Value Type="Text">Approved</Value>
</Eq>
</Where>
</Query>
```

Now use REST query using ajax. On Success method get the count of items.

http://chuvash.eu/2014/03/25/using-caml-with-sharepoint-rest-api/

Comment: Is it not possible by just using javascript

Comment: What you mean by just JavaScript? You need to use either JavaScript Object Model or REST API

Comment: I don't know anything about REST API

Answer (score 1):

**Just modified little bit, so it can be used as such**

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getDistinctItemsFromList,  "sp.js");

function getDistinctItemsFromList(listname) {

var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

var web = context.get_web();

var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('listname');

var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();

allItems = list.getItems(query);

context.load(allItems);

context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.success), Function.createDelegate(this, this.failed));

}

function success() {

var itemCount = allItems.get_count();

var itemsarry = new Array(parseInt(itemCount) - 1);

var ListEnumerator = this.allItems.getEnumerator();

for (var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {

itemsarry[i] = new Array(0);

itemsarry[i][0] = allItems.get_item(i).get_item('Columnname');

}

var uniqueItemsCount = 0;

var uniqueItems = {};

$.each(itemsarry, function () {

var num = this[0];

uniqueItems[num] = uniqueItems[num] + 1 || 1;

uniqueItemsCount++;

});


var j = 0;

$.each(uniqueItems, function (itemValue, noOfItems) {

if (itemValue != 'undefined');

{
alert(itemValue);

alert(noOfItems);

j++;

}
});

}

function failed(sender, args) {

alert("failed. Message:" + args.get_message());

}
```

Comment: can it be done out of the box?

Comment: Hello, What modifications should i need to do to save the noOfItems to a column?